# html download file parameters

Tags: html, download

Is there a way to download a file from the browser with parameters that will be passed to the file when running it?
For example, clicking on a link in my website will ask me if I want to download and run a msi/exe, and if I click on 'Run', parameters which are specific to the user will be passed to the msi/exe execution?

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

no. i dont think so. but you can ask for user information before downloading, add it in your database and use it in your coding for the exe/msi application.

Answer (score 0):

Can the code you are writing access your server via curl or any other means?  if so, you could store the parameters server side in a database or file which is associated with the user's IP address and then retrieve them on execution.